# When upgrading to mongodb 3.0, should I upgrade authentication schema after upgrading the storage engine to WiredTiger?

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I know that, I need to upgrade the storage engine after upgrading the binaries.
But I am not very sure whether I should upgrade the authentication after upgrading the storage engine. Or it does not matter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on a system administration site, Super User or Server Fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of the MongoDB 3.0 upgrade it is strongly recommended that you upgrade to the [SCRAM-SHA-1](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/) authentication scheme. New users will have their credentials created in this format by default; mixed authentication schemas will likely lead to confusion.

You will need to upgrade your client driver & admin tools (if you're using a GUI) in order to use the WiredTiger storage engine. Drivers/tools that have been updated for MongoDB 3.0 will also support the new authentication method.

As per the note on the SCRAM-SHA-1 documentation (referring to a future major release which would like be 3.2.x):

> The next major version of MongoDB is likely to remove all support for MONGODB-CR.

Comment: Should I upgrade the authentication scheme **before** upgrading to use WireTiger? Or Should I upgrade the authentication scheme **after** upgrading to use WireTiger? Or **it does not matter???**

Comment: The authentication schema does not matter to wiredTiger (it only handles details at the storage layer). Since you will need to update your drivers/tools to work with wiredTiger anyway, I think it makes sense to upgrade the authSchema as part of that same process. It would be confusing to have old/migrated users continuing to use the old MONGODB-CR schema and new users created with SCRAM-SHA-1. Upgrading the authSchema will ensure all users are using SCRAM-SHA-1, which is the preferred auth mechanism for MongoDB 3.0 and beyond.